# CreateJS (canvas) Iframe

Tags: javascript, createjs

Iframe ads example:

```
<iframe data-aa='1058853' src='//ad.a-ads.com/1058853?size=468x60' scrolling='no' style='width:468px; height:60px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden' allowtransparency='true'></iframe>
```

How to insert it into canvas using createJS?

The code of the whole function where I want to implement:

```
var _oBg;
var _oMsgText;
var _oContainer;

this._init = function(){
    _oContainer = new createjs.Container();
    s_oStage.addChild(_oContainer);

    // Sprite on background
    var oSprite = s_oSpriteLibrary.getSprite('msg_box');
    _oBg = createBitmap(oSprite);
    _oBg.x = CANVAS_WIDTH/2;
    _oBg.y = CANVAS_HEIGHT/2;
    _oBg.regX = oSprite.width/2;
    _oBg.regY = oSprite.height/2;
    _oContainer.addChild(_oBg);

    // Text on this background
    _oMsgText = new createjs.Text('any text',"46px "+PRIMARY_FONT, "#ffffff");
    _oMsgText.x = CANVAS_WIDTH/2;
    _oMsgText.y = 270;
    _oMsgText.textAlign = "center";
    _oContainer.addChild(_oMsgText);

    //Here I tried to insert iframe with ad
}
```

My try witch not working:

```
var oAds = document.createElement('iframe');
oAds.setAttribute('data-aa', '1058853');
oAds.setAttribute('src', '//ad.a-ads.com/1058853?size=468x60');
oAds.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
oAds.setAttribute('style', 'width:468px; height:60px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden');
oAds.setAttribute('allowtransparency', 'true');
// Tried new createjs.DOMElement(oAds) and others different ways
var ads = new createjs.Bitmap(oAds);
_oContainer.addChild(ads);
```

Attempt without a container (which is very bad, it is desirable in the container), ad appears behind the canvas (in the background and is not visible):

```
var oAds = document.createElement('iframe');
oAds.setAttribute('data-aa', '1058852');
oAds.setAttribute('src', 'https://ad.a-ads.com/1058852%3Fsize=468x60');
oAds.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
oAds.setAttribute('style', 'width:468px; height:60px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden');
oAds.setAttribute('allowtransparency', 'true');
document.body.appendChild(oAds);
```

ps. I suffer the second day and nothing comes out...
I read all documentations (EaseJS) and can't find how to solve my problem

Comment: That is likely not possible at all, because the Same Origin Policy should prevent your script from accessing the iframe content which was loaded from a different origin …

Comment: No, i tried native js and get some result, updated question

Comment: You might need to wait for the iframe to be loaded before you can modify contents on the stage. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @Lanny, no one error in console